# Google Developer Console "Try the new design" link

Tags: android

I have a Google account and have already posted some apps to the Developer Console for Beta testing. I'm now trying to do something with In-App billing. I'm following the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html). I'm down to Step 2 of Add Your Application to the Developer Console, "Click on the Try new design to access the preview version of the Developer Console, if you are not already logged on to that version. ". I don't see any such link. How can I tell which version I'm logged into?

Comment: Probably the new one, the switch was some time ago, I doubt you still have the old one. I guess you may have never known the old interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new design referenced in that documentation was [intially opened for preview](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/10/new-google-play-developer-console.html) back in October 2012.

As of March 2013, [it was no longer in preview](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/now-is-time-to-switch-to-new-google.html) and at this point everyone is using the "new" design. You don't need to do anything for that step.

The documentation is simply outdated.